# Inequality with martingales

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

(Reading *Merging, Reputation, and Repeated Games with
Incomplete Information* by Sylvian Sorin and trying to understand a probabilistic argument):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space equipped with a filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_n\}$ (increasing sequence of sub σ-fields of $\mathcal{F}$).
We assume that each σ-field $\mathcal{F}_n$ is generated by a countable partition $\mathcal{F}_n^*$ and we denote by $F_n(\omega)$ the atom of $\mathcal{F}_n^*$ containing $\omega$.

Let $q=\{q_m\}$ be a martingale with values $[0,1]$.

Let $m,M>0$ such that $\mathbb{E}_P\left[(q_{m+1}-q_m)^2\right]\leq\frac{1}{M}$.

The article claims that this bound implies that
$P\left(\omega;\mathbb{E}_P\left[(q_{m+1}-q_m)^2\mid F_{m-1}(\omega)\right]\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}\right)\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{M}}$.

I'm struggling to find the inequality \ property used for this conclusion. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Do you know Markov's inequality?

Comment: @jakobdt, Indeed, and for the chance that there are multiple ones with the same name, Its the one that states that given a non negative RV $X$, then
$P(X\geq t)\leq\frac{E(X)}{t}$

Comment: @jakobdt Got it now, feel kind of silly I didn't see it immediately. Thank you for the quick response!